# Arrays are nil after initializing in singleton class

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, nsmutablearray

I have a singleton class and I initialize 2 arrays like this.

```
- (id)init {
if (self = [super init]) {

        //----------------- request Array -------------------

    // obj 00
    listRequestArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableDictionary *tratype=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [tratype setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt:-1] forKey:@"ride_type_id"];
    [tratype setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"request_id"];
    [listRequestArr addObject:tratype];

    // obj 01
    NSMutableDictionary *ridename=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [ridename setValue: @"" forKey:@"ride_name"];
    [listRequestArr addObject:ridename];

    // obj 02
    NSMutableDictionary *rideprice=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [rideprice setValue: @"" forKey:@"ride_price"];
    [rideprice setValue: @"-1" forKey:@"ride_cid"];
    [rideprice setValue: @"" forKey:@"ride_price_name"];
    [listRequestArr addObject:rideprice];

    // obj 03
    NSMutableDictionary *reqdesc=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [reqdesc setValue: @"" forKey:@"request_desc"];
    [listRequestArr addObject:reqdesc];

    // obj 04
    NSMutableDictionary *modesoft=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [modesoft setValue: @"" forKey:@"modes_str"];
    [listRequestArr addObject:modesoft];

    // obj 05
    NSMutableDictionary *origindes=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [origindes setValue: @"" forKey:@"origin_add"];
    [origindes setValue:nil forKey:@"origin_placemark"];
    [origindes setValue: @"" forKey:@"des_add"];
    [origindes setValue:nil forKey:@"des_placemark"];
    [listRequestArr addObject:origindes];

    // obj 06
    NSMutableDictionary *availability=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [availability setValue: @"" forKey:@"ret_or_one_way"];
    [availability setValue: @"" forKey:@"depdate1"];
    [availability setValue: @"" forKey:@"depdate2"];
    [availability setValue: @"" forKey:@"retdate1"];
    [availability setValue: @"" forKey:@"retdate2"];
    [listRequestArr addObject:availability];

    // obj 07
    NSMutableDictionary *passengers=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [passengers setValue: @"0" forKey:@"adult"];
    [passengers setValue: @"0" forKey:@"child"];
    [passengers setValue: @"0" forKey:@"infants"];
    [listRequestArr addObject:passengers];




    requestCompletion=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        [requestCompletion addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0]];




     return self;


}
```

Inside one of my `ViewController` I set

```
dm=[Datamanager sharedmanager];
dm.listRequestArr=nil;
dm.requestCompletionArr=nil;
```

This  happen when I complete the webservice calling. After complete the web service call If I start to make another request although I did dm=[Datamanager sharedmanager] these 2 arrays are still nil; seems like it doesnt initialize what I have done in the `Datamanager` class. What is the reason for this? Please help me. Fisrt time it works but second time it doesnt after I set them to nil.

Thanks

Comment: You set `dm.listRequestArr=nil;`, what do you want?

Comment: because I want to refresh my table view after completing some action

Comment: I don't understand your problem clearly. `dm=[Datamanager sharedmanager];
dm.listRequestArr=nil;` so `listRequestArr` will be nil. What's your problem?

Comment: I set it to nil when dismiss the viewcontroller. when I re open the view controller I wanna re initialize these 2 arrays like first time it happened

Comment: Why do you need a singleton then? Why not just use a factory

Comment: I use singleton because many view controllers should refer these 2 arrays

Comment: I have a UITableView in one viewcontroller there are other 5 viewcontrollers connected with that (did select row at index can navigate to each) If one request completed it redirect to the tableviewcontroller so table view indicate putting a tick in the particular cell saying that request is completed. If all the 5 requests completed from those 5 viewcontrollers 5 cells should be ticked and enable a publish button inside that table view controller. That publish button is my web service caller. after done publishing wanna clear UITable and the other viewcontrollers too.

Comment: don't use `dm.listRequestArr=nil;`, use `[dm.listRequestArr removeAllObjects]`, its safer to remove all objects and don't have to alloc init it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

1) You don't need singleton and each view controller may use its own hence only setup once.

2) You want to *DESTROY* the singleton instance and so expose a method reinit() or clear() for this purpose.

Using your code, a possible 'reset()' method would be:

```
- (id)init {
if (self = [super init]) {
     [self reset];
     return self;
}

-(void) reset {
        //----------------- request Array -------------------

    // obj 00
    listRequestArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableDictionary *tratype=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [tratype setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt:-1] forKey:@"ride_type_id"];
    [tratype setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"request_id"];
    [listRequestArr addObject:tratype];

    // obj 01
    NSMutableDictionary *ridename=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [ridename setValue: @"" forKey:@"ride_name"];
    [listRequestArr addObject:ridename];

    // obj 02
    NSMutableDictionary *rideprice=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [rideprice setValue: @"" forKey:@"ride_price"];
    [rideprice setValue: @"-1" forKey:@"ride_cid"];
    [rideprice setValue: @"" forKey:@"ride_price_name"];
    [listRequestArr addObject:rideprice];

    // obj 03
    NSMutableDictionary *reqdesc=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [reqdesc setValue: @"" forKey:@"request_desc"];
    [listRequestArr addObject:reqdesc];

    // obj 04
    NSMutableDictionary *modesoft=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [modesoft setValue: @"" forKey:@"modes_str"];
    [listRequestArr addObject:modesoft];

    // obj 05
    NSMutableDictionary *origindes=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [origindes setValue: @"" forKey:@"origin_add"];
    [origindes setValue:nil forKey:@"origin_placemark"];
    [origindes setValue: @"" forKey:@"des_add"];
    [origindes setValue:nil forKey:@"des_placemark"];
    [listRequestArr addObject:origindes];

    // obj 06
    NSMutableDictionary *availability=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [availability setValue: @"" forKey:@"ret_or_one_way"];
    [availability setValue: @"" forKey:@"depdate1"];
    [availability setValue: @"" forKey:@"depdate2"];
    [availability setValue: @"" forKey:@"retdate1"];
    [availability setValue: @"" forKey:@"retdate2"];
    [listRequestArr addObject:availability];

    // obj 07
    NSMutableDictionary *passengers=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [passengers setValue: @"0" forKey:@"adult"];
    [passengers setValue: @"0" forKey:@"child"];
    [passengers setValue: @"0" forKey:@"infants"];
    [listRequestArr addObject:passengers];




    requestCompletion=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        [requestCompletion addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0]];
}
```

Make sure to add in your header file for the class

```
-(void) reset;
```

Comment: How can I destroy the singleton instance?

Comment: I imagine you use dispatch_once? (although the code is not pasted). Simply add a method that can go _sharedInstance = [[Datamanager alloc] init]

Comment: you could take the code out of init and call it setup method, and then from init call setup, but also expose setup so you can do it any time you like

Comment: It's rough but check the amended answer for simplicity

Answer (score 0):

Singleton is just alloc one time when app live. After firs time call it have alloc and you set it to nil again. So second time: it still nil. It normal. You should check it nil and alloc it again.